# When was the freedom of speech part of the 1st Amendment first applied to the executive and judiciary?

Tags: united-states, first-amendment, incorporation

the first Amendment states:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the Government for a redress of grievances.

This only mentions congress explicitly. According to https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/incorporation_doctrine

> The First Amendment has been interpreted by the Court as applying to the entire federal government even though it is only expressly applicable to Congress.

I would like to find the first court case where the first amendment was applied like this to the entire federal government(judiciary or executive).

Can you help?

Comment: The US President and the Supreme Court don't make laws. Otherwise your link goes into plenty of detail about incorporation.

Comment: To elaborate what @pboss3010 said, the President implements and enforces the laws and the Judiciary interprets the laws... If congress cannot make a law on a matter, the President cannot enforce a law and the courts cannot make interpretations about the law (SCOTUS can interprit if a law is in complaince with the First Amendment).

Comment: @hszmv there can be unconstitutional arrests for a common-law offense, with no statute involved. See *Cantwell v Ct* in my answer .

Comment: @DavidSiegel:  Just because they legally cannot does not mean in practice they cannot.   That's why we have the word "unconstitutional".   A common-law offense means that the "law" was made by case law setting legal precidence.   My state, for example, doesn't have a codfied murder law because our courts long said "Murder is ilegal".   THe only murder rules we have on the books are sentencing guidelines and there's never been a need to actually codify a legal definition for Murder.  And my state is not unusual in this respect.

Comment: @hszmv you wrote "If congress cannot make a law on a matter, the President cannot enforce a law and the courts cannot make interpretations about the law" This seemed to imply that there is never need to apply 1st ad to admin or judicial actions. My point was that even if Congress (or state legislature) never passed an invalid law (which it does) unconstitutional uses of common law can and do exist. I agree with all that you said in your most recent comment.

Comment: The President issues Executive Orders. He's the Commander-in-Chief of the military. He has broad authority over foreign affairs. He can control the speech of the Ambassadors and embassy staffs. Federal departments and agencies promulgate regulations. There's a lot of opportunity for the Executive Branch to abridge Freedom of Speech.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the 21st century's idea of "freedom of speech" based on precedent?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38677/is-the-21st-centurys-idea-of-freedom-of-speech-based-on-precedent)

Comment: I'm marking this question as a duplicate because it not only asks the same question but also would have the same outcome of answers as a question that has already been asked https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/38677/is-the-21st-centurys-idea-of-freedom-of-speech-based-on-precedent.

Comment: @WimWollff:  Bit late to this party, but the ruling is that the government is allowed to restrict the speech of employees as if it was an employer without violating the First Amendment.  Even Congressmen and women can restrict their staffer's speech and fire them for improper speech.

Answer (score 2):

At least in terms of U.S. Supreme Court decisions, the earliest I know of was [*New York Times Co. v. United States*, 403 U.S. 713 (1971)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/403/713), which applied the standard First Amendment test for prior restraints to the judicial imposition of injunctions.

Answer (score 2):

[*Near v. Minnesota*, 283 U.S. 697 (1931)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/283/697/) also applied First Amendment standards to an injunction, overturning the injunction and holding the state law authorizing such injunctions to be unconstitutional, at least as applied in the *Near* case. I believe this case was cited in *New York Times Co. v. United States* (the "Pentagon Papers" case). This was a case of state, not federal action, and so it applied the 1st as incorporated via the 14th, not directly as in *New York Times Co. v. United States*. See also *Minnesota Rag* By Fred W. Friendly, the excellent book about the *Near* case.

There was also [*New York Times Co. v. Sullivan*, 376 U.S. 254 (1964)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/376/254/), the case that established the "actual malice" standard for defamation cases when the plaintiff is a public official (later expanded to "public figure"). Again this was a state case appealed to federal jurisdiction.  See also *Make No Law*, a very through book about the case.

There was also [*Cantwell v. Connecticut*, 310 U.S. 296 (1940)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/310/296/) in which an arrest for violation of a statute prohibiting solicitation of religious or charitable donations without a license and also for a common-law offense of breach of the peace was held unconstitutional. This is perhaps more of a case of an unconstitutional law being enforced, but arbitrary and hence unconstitutional administrative action in denying permits was mentioned in the decision.